# The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, render

I'm working on a piece of code that shows a random sponsor image on each webpage. I figured that the best place to call my function is in the Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml page, because that's the one that loads at every page.

I wrote the function in a service class in my domain model, and wrote a `ChildActionOnly` function in my homecontroller, returns the value in a simple view in Views/Home/Randomsponsor.cshtml and called the function in the shared layout with a Html.action.

Everything builds fine, but while running i get the next error:

```
{"The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController."}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this one?

Method in the domain project:

```
public String advertsForCountry()
{
    String studentSchool = finder.getLoggedStudent().SchoolId;
    int studentCountry = db.Schools.Find(studentSchool).CountryId;

    List<Sponsor> sponsorsForStudent = new List<Sponsor>();
    List<Advert> adverts = db.Adverts.ToList();
    foreach(Advert adv in adverts)
    {
        foreach(Country cntry in adv.Countries)
        {
            if(cntry.CountryId == studentCountry)
            {
                sponsorsForStudent.Add(adv.Sponsor);
            }
        }
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomSP = random.Next(0, sponsorsForStudent.Count()-1);
    string sponsorAdvert = sponsorsForStudent.ElementAt(randomSP).SponsorCompany;
    return sponsorAdvert;       
}
```

In HomeController:

```
[HttpGet]   
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult RandomSponsor()
{
    var model = service.advertsForCountry();

    return PartialView("RandomSponsor", model);
}
```

Simple view in Views/Home/ :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RandomSponsor";
}

@Html.Action("RandomSponsor")
```

And my function call in the View/Shared/_Layout.cshtml whitch contains the navigation bar, etc:

```
@Html.Action("RandomSponsor", "HomeController")
```

Regards.

Comment: Try using `@Html.Action("RandomSponsor", "Home")` instead of `@Html.Action("RandomSponsor", "HomeController")`

Comment: @wgraham. That did the job, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Converted from comment)

You don't need to specify the full class name of the Controller in `Html.Action`. Try using  `@Html.Action("RandomSponsor", "Home")` instead of `@Html.Action("RandomSponsor", "HomeController")`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the name of the controller. Please note, when you create a controller and called it Alexie, by default MVC will name it `AlexieController`. Therefore, when you are calling a function within a controller, it should be like this:

```
@Html.Action("Function Name", "Alexie").
And not like this:
@Html.Action("Function Name", "AlexieController").
```

So, I agreed with wgraham's answer.